# Unable to check all check boxes in a GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox, preview

[image]I am using grid view check box to select all the values in the grid view when i click the check box, but the problem i am facing is it is selecting the only the first page value how ever i have coded to bring all the values in but in design it is not working out

this is the image

[image]

i want all the check box to checked in design when i press the all check button.

```
 protected void gvBatch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header && e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Footer && e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager)
            {
                DropDownList ddlcountry1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlcountry");
                populateLocationValues(ddlcountry1);
                {
                    ArrayList checkboxvalues = (ArrayList)Session["BP_PrdId"];
                    //string Bp_Id = "";
                    if (checkboxvalues != null && checkboxvalues.Count > 0)
                    {

                        string strBp_Id = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hf_ProductLblId")).Value.ToString();
                        if (checkboxvalues.Contains(strBp_Id))
                        {
                            CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkPLPSltItem");
                            myCheckBox.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                DataSet dsaccess = MenuRestriction();
                DataRow dr = null;
                string sView = "";
                string sEdit = "";
                string sInsert = "";
                string sDeactive = "";

                if (dsaccess.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (dsaccess.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dr = dsaccess.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                        sView = dr["MnuRgts_View"].ToString();
                        sEdit = dr["MnuRgts_Edit"].ToString();
                        sInsert = dr["MnuRgts_Insert"].ToString();
                        sDeactive = dr["MnuRgts_DeActivate"].ToString();

                        if (sInsert == "Y" && sDeactive == "Y")
                        {
                            BtnDelete.Visible = true;
                            imgNew.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BtnDelete.Visible = false;
                            imgNew.Visible = false;

                            if (sInsert == "Y")
                            {
                                imgNew.Visible = true;
                            }
                            if (sDeactive == "Y")
                            {
                                BtnDelete.Visible = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("gvBatch_RowDataBound", ex);
        }
    }
  protected void gvBatch_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RememberOldValues();
            gvBatch.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            //RetrieveValues();
            BindGrid();
            LoadLocation();
            //RePopulateValues();
        }
   private void RememberOldValues()
    {
        ArrayList checkboxvalues = new ArrayList();
        string strBp_Id = "";
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvBatch.Rows)
        {
            //index = (int)gvBatch.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
            strBp_Id = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hf_ProductLblId")).Value.ToString();
            bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPLPSltItem")).Checked;

            // Check in the Session
            if (Session["BP_PrdId"] != null)
                checkboxvalues = (ArrayList)Session["BP_PrdId"];
            if (result)
            {
                if (!checkboxvalues.Contains(strBp_Id))
                    checkboxvalues.Add(strBp_Id);
            }
            else
            {
                if (checkboxvalues.Contains(strBp_Id))
                    checkboxvalues.Remove(strBp_Id);
            }
        }
        if (checkboxvalues != null && checkboxvalues.Count > 0)
            Session["BP_PrdId"] = checkboxvalues;
    }
protected void gvBatch_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (gvBatch.TopPagerRow != null)
            {
                ((Label)gvBatch.TopPagerRow.FindControl("lbCurrentPage")).Text = (gvBatch.PageIndex + 1).ToString();
                ((Label)gvBatch.TopPagerRow.FindControl("lbTotalPages")).Text = gvBatch.PageCount.ToString();

                ((LinkButton)gvBatch.TopPagerRow.FindControl("lbtnFirst")).Visible = gvBatch.PageIndex != 0;
                ((LinkButton)gvBatch.TopPagerRow.FindControl("lbtnPrev")).Visible = gvBatch.PageIndex != 0;
                ((LinkButton)gvBatch.TopPagerRow.FindControl("lbtnNext")).Visible = gvBatch.PageCount != (gvBatch.PageIndex + 1);
                ((LinkButton)gvBatch.TopPagerRow.FindControl("lbtnLast")).Visible = gvBatch.PageCount != (gvBatch.PageIndex + 1);

                DropDownList ddlist = (DropDownList)gvBatch.TopPagerRow.FindControl("ddlPageItems");
                ddlist.SelectedIndex = ddlist.Items.IndexOf(ddlist.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["DropDownPageItems"].ToString()));
                gvBatch.AllowPaging = true;
                gvBatch.TopPagerRow.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    protected void gvBatch_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "EDIT")
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;
                string strAgentName = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hf_loginName")).Value.ToString();
                if (strAgentName != "")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("CustomerDetails.aspx?Name=" + strAgentName, false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("gvAgentRowcommand_AgentSummary", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So where is the code to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a boolean field in your code and set its value to `true` whenever the select all is clicked. When loading new pages, you can check that field to automatically display all checked. The same can be done when exporting the grid also.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify and use the following Method

```
private void selectAllChecksInDAtaGrid()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in myDataGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells["Column_Name"].Value) == false)
            {
                item.Cells["Column_Name"].Value = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

the 'Column_name' is the name of  the checkbox column. if you haven'nt named it yet you can also use the index number .
in your case its 0

```
private void selectAllChecksInDAtaGrid()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in myDataGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value) == false)
            {
                item.Cells[0].Value = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update `(ArrayList)Session["BP_PrdId"]` to include all the "Id"s of datasource of gridview. then bind data again.